# Unable to ask a question using Safari

Tags: support, asking-questions, browser-support

I am using my Google browser to ask this question because Safari seems not to be letting me ask a question on Stack Overflow. Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

Typically, you would see the next button underneath the title, but here you don't. I could not find it anywhere.

[image]

I have turned off the Ask Wizard too, but nothing seems to work.

Is this a bug? What can I do to resolve this?

I'm using:

- macOS Monterey 12.2.1.
- Safari 15.3 (17612.4.9.1.8).
- No extensions/userscripts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your version of Safari is, for a browser, quite old. The [oldest version of Safari which Stack Overflow, currently, supports is 17.3](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/). You will need to update your browser.